# Using request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') in URL reverse in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form in my template and when the form is submitted I'm trying to redirect back to the URL where the form originally was along with some arguments

Here is how I'm doing it

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
    url = reverse(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'), kwargs={'groups': groups, 'product': product})
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

This gives me an error

```
u'http' is not a registered namespace
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reverse` expects a view name.

Either do like this and lose most of your arguments unless you build them with some form of string interpolation

```
url = "{0}/{1}".format(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'), your_args)

return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

or decide that the view you're currently trying to redirect from always redirects to the same place ie.

```
url = reverse('form_landing_view', kwargs={'groups':groups, 'product': product})
```

The third option would be using [resolve()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.resolve).

Comment: You mean like this `url = reverse('form_landing_view', kwargs={'sku_id': 5})` ?